# How to show $ \lim_{(h, k) \to (0, 0)} {-2 hk^2 \sqrt{h^2 + k^2} \over (h^2 + k^2)^2 } $ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that the limit does not exist
$$  \lim_{(h, k) \to (0, 0)} {-2 hk^2 \sqrt{h^2 + k^2} \over (h^2 + k^2)^2 } $$

Thank you in advance for your explanations.

Comment: Show us your efforts. What ideas do you have to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, I need to prove that the limit either does not exist or it does not equal to 0. I just don't have any clues, that's why I am asking for hints.

Comment: Take different sequences $0 \neq (h_n, k_n) \to 0$ and look what happens. If you are unable to compute anything, take other sequences. Start with the easiest sequences you can imagine.

Comment: **Hint:** Use polar coordinates $h=\rho\cos{\varphi}, \ k=\rho\sin{\varphi}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Take the limit along the line $k=-h$ as $h\rightarrow 0^{+}$. What limit do you get?

Take the limit along the line $k=-h$ as $h\rightarrow 0^{-}$. What limit do you get?

(If you can show that the limit as $(h,k)\rightarrow 0$, is different along different sequences, or different lines, then that means the required limit does not actually exist.)

Comment: do you mean $h=k$ or $h=-k$